# Constructing connection string knowing server name and db name

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database

I have SQL Server 2014 installed on my machine and on connect to server dialog in SQL Server Management Studio I'm logging with following credentials

```
Server name: .\
Auth. windows authentication
User name: MYPC\LENOVO W540
Password:
```

after successful login my db is accessible under following name:

```
DB_74432_sales
```

Question is: how should I construct my connection string in `web.config`?

I tried this:

```
<add name="DbConnectionString" 
     connectionString="Data Source=.\;Database=DB_74432_sales;Integrated Security=True;" />
```

Can someone confirm me that this is wrong cause I'm getting an error message that instance name cannot be found

Comment: Try `(local);` instead  in your `Data Source`. See also here [The Connection Strings Reference](https://www.connectionstrings.com/)

Comment: If you installed a default instance of SQL Express then it will be `.\SQLEXPRESS`. It will be easy to check - just look in the "Control Panel" -> "Administrative Tools" -> "Services". BTW, you should create a user account specifically for SQL Server before you install it; the installation process will assign the necessary permissions for the account.

Answer (score 0):

If you see that DB_74432_sales is at the top of the object explorer in SQL Server Management Studio, this is how your connection string is formed.

```
<add name="DbConnectionString" 
     connectionString="Data Source=DB_74432_sales;Database=[Name of your Database];Integrated Security=True;" />
```

Name of your database is the one you click in the object explorer, usually the 3rd level of the node.

Comment: thanks for correcting my wordings for SQL Server Management Studio @marc_s.